# Option text overflowing out of browser in Select dropdown

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a drop down list in my AngularJS app using `<select>`. When an option text is too long, the drop down overflows out of the browser window like this:

[image]

I tried adding divs and specifying fixed width with `overflow-x:auto`. Also tried text wrapping but nothing works. This is the html of my drop down:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Status*</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="cmbStatus" ng-model="cmbStatusSelected"        
            ng-options="item.attribValue for item in lstCaseStatus">
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ah the uncooperative selects.  These guys are notoriously rebellious.  You probably have already looked around and found some older suggestions on how to deal with these guys, but you will discover that what once worked no longer does, or only works in a couple of browsers, or on desktops but not mobile etc.

Unfortunately there is no CSS solution I know of that is dependable, and if it one was found that works across all major browsers and platforms, that does not mean it will continue to be a viable solution tomorrow.  This is typical of form elements because so much is left up the the browser developers themselves to control behavior and default styling.

So as with any form element, about the only option you have for a dependable consistent cross platform solution is to replace the form element. Hiding the native element and putting a more compliant impostor in its place.

For form selects Chosen.js is often the go to library.  I believe  'ag-select' is an implementation of Chosen that will help you out here.   https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources

Otherwise the other solution is to truncate your option text on the backend to a set character width.   If you already have a bunch of selects in your project and don't want to have to go back and implement ng-select on all of them, then truncating your labels may be the best solution.

Comment: thank you for such a detail answer. Its a bummer that there's no simple and viable solution for such an obvious problem. `ng-select` does seem like it will help solve my problem, but going for third party solutions was something I was trying to avoid in the first place.